# Rename the slave Postgresql database name

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave-replication

I have Master-Slave streaming replication working well with postgresql 13. I created the slave from the master successfully and data is synching nicely to the slave. Can I just change the name of the slave database now? When configuring the master-slave replication, there was no single place to specify the database name. So if I just rename the slave db name and restart the slave server, will everything work fine? Just asking before I am doing it.

Comment: Since the clusters are kept identical, the only way to rename a database on the standby is to rename it on the primary. The changed name will be replicated.

Comment: There are many things that might be loosely referred to as the database name.  Are you taking about the "real" one, the argument used for `dbname`, or to something else like the display name given in the AWS console?

Comment: If the master db is dev, I want to rename the slave to "dev-replica". So isn't this possible? There is nothing to do with AWS. I am talking about changing the actual database name (not the server/host name)

Comment: Ok, I tried it myself by executing the `alter database <db-name> rename to <new-db-name>`. That doesn't work. It gives me the error "cannnot execute update in a read-only transaction". So nothing can be updated in the slave database unless I change it to be non-slave database I assume.